# How to use HTML5 tag and css3 in IE6-8?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

I am use HTML5 tag and CSS in my page.
so it is not working in IE6-8.
so I am use html5.js but also not working.
and also use ie7-squish.js.
so what's problem in my code.
or
any other methods or js is available.
please help me.
Thanks in Advance.
My HTML code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <style type="text/css">
        body {
            padding-top: 40px;
            padding-bottom: 40px;
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
          }
          .form-signin {
            max-width: 300px;
            padding: 19px 29px 29px;
            margin: 0 auto 20px;
            background-color: #fff;
            border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
            -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
               -moz-border-radius: 5px;
                    border-radius: 5px;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
               -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
                    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
          }
          .form-signin .form-signin-heading,
          .form-signin .checkbox {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
          }
          .form-signin input[type="text"],
          .form-signin input[type="password"] {
            font-size: 16px;
            height: auto;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
            padding: 7px 9px;
          }
        </style>
        <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="container">
          <form class="form-signin">
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
            <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Email address">
            <input type="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Password">
            <label class="checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
            </label>
            <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What's not working? As far as I can make out, the only HTML5 feature you're using is the placeholder attribute of input. Could you not just stick a label next to the field rather than rely on placeholder to prompt the user? I don't believe attribute selectors are supported in IE 6 (see selectors for the form elements in your CSS) , but you could easily work around that.

Answer (score 0):

see the following link, this might be useful, though perfect rendering might not be possible.
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-make-all-browsers-render-html5-mark-up-correctly-even-ie6/

Answer (score 0):

Try chrome frame, it's a plug-in for Internet Explorer: http://www.google.com/chromeframe?quickenable=true

Comment: Yes but that means anyone viewing his page from IE would need a specific plugin, which is not a good design choice.

Comment: Also Chrome Frame is being discontinued by Google in January 2014